# Calculate the CSS top and Left based on Video size

Tags: c#, css, mathematical-optimization, video.js

I'm currently trying to decipher how to adjust a digital zoom in my CSS on a JSvideo component based on changes in screen size. Lets say my video thumbnail is zoomed in at the right point:

Width 160px
Height 100px
Top -147
left -70

These bring the correct part of the video into view. Now when the video expands to normal size the coords end up like this (which is wrong):
Width 890px
Height 450px
Top - 1050px
Left - 500px

What it should end up as to maintain the same zoom area on the video is:
Top -850
Left -400

CSS, JavaScript and C# answers are welcome

I've tried various base calculations to no avail. Anyone?

Comment: You should include some examples of what you have tried, this is to avoid us posting solutions that don't work in your scenario. A [mre] will also help us to respond in terms and syntax that you may be familiar with